# How to get some specific ID by several columns with the same title SQL ANDROID

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

How to get some specific ID by several columns with the same title i Want to get the price of all computers together Here is a picture that will explain better
 [This My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlhXr.png)

I want to get all the prices of computers of all computers

I'm sorry if I'm not clear, but I do not know how to explain it well

Comment: Sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, please.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works for you, `select id, price from table_name where item = 'Computer'`
You can join the result with description from other table